# Virtual box shared folder is not mounted in guest

Tags: virtualbox

I'm trying to mount a Windows host folder `D:\Code` to a Linux guest system.
To do that, I added it in shared folders (two attempts - both didn't work):
[image: My machine settings]

And there is list of folders on guest Linux system in this state:

[image: A list of folders on the guest Linux system]

My added `D:\Code` folder is not mounted. But as you can see there is a `c` folder which contains `Users` (shared from host `C:\Users`)

What I expected is to see `code` and `d` on the Linux guest system, but it didn't happen.
Did I forget to do something?

Answer (score 1):

Found the aswer there:
http://www.developmentalmadness.com/2016/02/27/working-with-docker/

Need to use commands in lunux:

```
mkdir /mnt/src
mount -t vboxsf code /mnt/code
```